# Reverse Proxy Rules Removed automatically from Cpanel httpd.conf file after server update

Tags: linux, apache, cpanel, reverse-proxy, whm

I am getting en error in Apache since long time.
And the issue is that after some time, reverse proxy rules removed from Apache virtual host automatically.

Is there anyone who can help me out on this issue ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved now, with the help of Cpanel support team.

**#Cpanel_Reply**

The most common reason that a configuration setting would get removed from WHM/Cpanel when rebuilding the httpd.conf file is because the modification was done directly to the configuration file. When cPanel rebuilds the apache conf, it does so using template files and any configuration not in those templates are not included.

**#Solution**

cPanel Apache Reverse Proxy

**Step 1. Download The Proxy Script**

wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/varunsridharan/cpanel-apache-proxy/main/proxy.sh

**Step 2. Run To Create A New Proxy**

sh proxy.sh "cpanelAccountName" "blog.example.com" "http://192.168.1.41:32000"

**Step 3. Rebuild & Restart HTTP**
/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf && service httpd restart

Regards
Subhash sautiyal
tech2towards